# How to clone Flutter Gallery project in my Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, flutter

Link: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/master/examples/flutter_gallery

but when I try to test before clone, it's showing "repository test failed"
but my git is installed in my Kali Linux and also I previously so many times clone projects, but I think this flutter gallery is not correct to clone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you installed flutter then you have it at `<flutter_install_path>/examples/flutter_gallery`

[image: path]

Comment: How can I open from AS directly?

Comment: I found path from flutter SDK and trying to open from AS using open existing project, but then it saysDownload Dark SDK. Now why it is necessary, I already made a flutter project usiing "start a new flutter project", and everything sets up already then why again dark sdk?

Comment: just open the folder normally

Comment: don't make a new project just open the folder

Comment: my dear, I did same. when I opened folder it says to download dark sdk n all

Comment: can you post a screenshot? my AS doesn't have a problem here. Looks like the path is not configured

Comment: if AS can successfully open the folder it will ask you to update `pubspec.yaml`. If not then fix the path

Comment: exception after downloaded dart sdk and sat path from AS: Because flutter_gallery depends on flutter_goldens any from sdk which doesn't exist (the Flutter SDK is not available), version solving failed.

Flutter users should run `flutter pub get` instead of `pub get`

Comment: Open AS -> Settings-> Languages/Framework -> Flutter-> search for the folder where you have flutter installed . This will go into `Flutter SDK option`. Also you will need plugins for dart and flutter. See edit in answer

Answer (score 0):

Another way is just to download it from the github website

First go to the root of the project which i think is this=> https://github.com/flutter/flutter 
click on the **clone or download** button and download **the zip version** of the project
**extract it**, on your computer
Now use your **IDE** to open it

Comment: I found path from flutter SDK and trying to open from AS using open existing project, but then it saysDownload Dark SDK. Now why it is necessary, I already made a flutter project usiing "start a new flutter project", and everything sets up already then why again dark sdk?

Comment: you don't need to download dartsdk just set the path for flutter, thats it

Comment: but that is already done na, that's why I still can create a new flutter project. isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

For me and after 3 days of searching and testing:
Download the flutter SDK  manually from [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#get-sdk)
Then open android studio -> configuration -> setting -> languages & Frameworks -> flutter:
locate Flutter SDK path to the source you just downloaded
Then click apply